# MVC5 - Upload multiple images not providing collection of files

Tags: c#, image, file-upload, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm new to MVC, and attempting to build a page to upload multiple images to my site. However, the ***Request.Files*** collection contains strings, all containing "FileUpload". I have read many of the multiple file uploads from this site, but none appear to work. I'm not certain where I'm going wrong and would appreciate some experienced eyes to assist. Once I can get the proper file info, I can upload to my site.

Thank you for the assistance,
Allan

Source files included below.

## ImagesController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MyApp.Controllers
{
    public class ImagesController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Images/Upload
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Upload()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Images/Upload
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Upload(FormCollection formCollection)
        {
            try
            {
                HttpFileCollectionBase files = Request.Files;
                foreach(HttpPostedFileBase file in files)
                {
                    int length = file.ContentLength;
                    string type = file.ContentType;
                    string filename = file.FileName;
                 }
                 return RedirectToAction("Upload");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## Upload.cshtml

```
@{Layout = null;}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Upload</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="~/Images/Upload" id="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <table style="margin:1px; background-color:#ccc;">
            <tr style="background-color:#fff;">
                <td><h1>File Upload Form</h1></td>
                <td rowspan="3">
                    @if (ViewData.Model != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var item in ViewData.Model)
                        {
                            <img src="/Images/@item["Path"]" alt="FileUpload     Image" />
                        }
                    }
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="background-color:#fff;">
                <td>
                    <input type="file" name="FileUpload" id="FileUpload"         multiple="multiple" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="background-color:#fff;">
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Upload"         id="btnSubmit" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer has been found, I had two major issues causing the code not to operate as expected.  The method declaration was flawed, it should read as:

`public ActionResult Upload(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> uploadFiles)`

Secondly, the input name in the view and the parameter in the declaration must match. Changing the view to use:

`<input type="file" name="uploadFiles" id="FileUpload" multiple="multiple" />`

Making these changes, allowed the controller to cycle through the images.

Thank you,
Allan